# Why can't we declare a local variable inside of function parentheses, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, declaration, parentheses

I don't understand this because java is my first programming language.

In java, variables inside of parentheses should be declared

For example

```
public int checkUserName(int minLength){
    //some codes 
}
```

but in javascript

```
function checkUsername(var minLength){
//some codes
}
```

shows an unexpected token var error

I know Java and JavaScript are two different languages but I just want to know why isn't it allowed in JavaScript. I know it is not allowed I just want to know why.

I asked this because my JavaScript book does not explain me why JavaScript does not allow that. It just says you should write so but not WHY.

Comment: in javascript you don't have to add the type of the value the argument must be

Comment: Why? Because different languages use different syntax. What you are asking is well documented

Comment: *"Is it so bad to ask WHY?"* No. But it really needed to be emphasized so people didn't misread it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you've clarified:

> I know [it isn't allowed] but I just wondered why isn't it allowed

Because until ES2015 it would have been completely redundant and pointless; just having `minLength` there is sufficient declaration, since JavaScript's variables and parameters are not typed. Moreover, `var` would have been misleading, as `minLength` isn't a variable, it's a *parameter*. (Functionally, they're very nearly the same thing as far as the function's code is concerned other than the obvious difference that the initial value of a parameter comes from outside the function; but they *aren't* the same thing.)

In ES2015 and above, there's an argument for allowing an optional `const` to indicate that the parameter's value can never be changed by the function, but I haven't seen any proposal for that advanced (so far).

Answer (score 2):

When I started to learn second language I had many similar questions, but when you learn third and so on you are just deal with it :) in every two languages you will find something similar and something different

you have not to declare `minLength` here

```
function checkUsername(var minLength) {
    //some codes 
}
```

try

```
function checkUsername(minLength) {
    //some codes 
}
```

You might be interested in TypeScript, it is javascript after all, but looks pretty similar to java. for example:

```
public checkUserName(minLength: int ): int {
    //some codes 
}
```

Comment: @ProgramLover because it's not allowed. it's that simple. That's syntax-rule.

Comment: Javascript does not work like Java. The names are similar but that does not mean the actual languages are close to each other